# Cucumber: web_steps.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

I'm wasting my time here and I can't seem to figure this out..

I have used Cucumber in Rails applications before, and if I'm not mistaken, it generates the  `features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb` file when you run `rails g cucumber:install`. Right?

I looked this up in a book I was using a while ago to learn Rails and it says so there aswell:

> It nevertheless passes because of the features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb
>   file, which was generated when you ran the rails generate cucumber:install command.

However, when I run it in this application I'm trying to start working on, it does not generate it..

```
$ rails g cucumber:install
      create  config/cucumber.yml
      create  script/cucumber
       chmod  script/cucumber
      create  features/step_definitions
      create  features/support
      create  features/support/env.rb
       exist  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/cucumber.rake
       force  config/database.yml
```

No `web_steps.rb` to be found. Am I losing my mind here?

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem reading through Rails 3 in Action.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Which version of cucumber are you using? if it is a recent version, see

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/f027440965b96b780e84e50dd47203a2838e8d7d/History.md

Comment: Ah, something new from the last couple of days I see. Thanks ;)

Comment: Reading the same book, got the same question, nice answer, thx.